# How to search for question mark and / with regular expression ? python

Tags: python, html, regex, python-2.7, html-parsing

I want to search a file for a number that match this pattern:

```
<a  href="test/?n=451484"   >
```

then get the number `451484` :

I use this pattern :

```
'
(test/?n=)
\d+
'
```

but that doesn't work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 changes

- escape the `?`
- wrap the `d+` in paranthesis
- drop paranthesis around `test\?n=`

Example usage

```
>>> import re
>>> str='<a  href="test/?n=451484"   >'
>>> re.findall(r'test/\?n=(\d+)', str)
['451484']
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but why I should wrap the d+ in paranthesis ?

Comment: @david it is required only if you are using `findall` as in my example. The findall saves the capturing groups and prints them, thus ignoring the matched `test..` and printing only the digits as required

Answer (score 0):

To search for a literal `?` character, you need to escape it with a `\`. `?` is a special character in regexes, and cannot (usually) be used on its own.

```
pattern = r"test/\?n=(\d+)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use specialized tools:

- an *HTML Parser* to parse the HTML data (for example, [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/))
- [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) to extract the url parameter value

Example:

```
import re
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div>
    <a href="test/?n=451484">link</a>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

# filtering links with a specific "href" attribute value    
link = soup.find('a', href=re.compile(r'test/\?n=\d+'))

url = link['href']
query = urlparse(url).query
print parse_qs(query)['n'][0]  # prints 451484
```